# Adding CURL Library To Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I Want To Use  library in my C++ code using VS2013, But it Doesn't Work, So I've searched about anyway to add the library to the VS but with no result !!

How To add this library to C++ ??

Comment: I've Downloaded the library from this link http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl-devel-msvc , then i tried to add it to Visual Studio files by copying library files to lib folder in VS but nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating a project and [downloading](http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl-devel-msvc) `libcurl` you'll want to extract the contents of the `libcurl` zip. Afterwards in MVS open your project and look for the solution explorer. Right click on your project and chose `Properties` at the bottom.

Under `Configuration Properties` -> `Linker` -> `General` add the folder `lib\Release` from where you extracted `libcurl`: `libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc\lib\Release` in the `Additional Library Directories` list.

Under `Configuration Properties` -> `Linker` -> `Input` add `curllib.lib` in the `Additional Dependencies` list.

Under `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `General` add `include\curl` from where you extracted `libcurl`: `libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc\include\curl` in the `Additional Include Directories` list.

Press `Ok` and you're done. You might even want to take a look at the `libcurl` examples [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html).

Comment: Under Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General , I've Opened This But i don't find any place to add the folder Release !!

Comment: @user3595420 Fixed it, add it in the `Additional Library Directories` list.

Comment: I've Followed Your Instructions but this errors appeared in some header file of CURL https://i.imgur.com/cX7p4BO.jpg

Comment: @user3595420 Did you try compiling a example? Such as [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html)?

Comment: I've Fixed The First Error By adding all the include folder not include/curl in the Configuration Properties , but now it compiles but it breaks when the console opens and this appears ==> http://i.imgur.com/M5BwOQq.jpg

Comment: @user3595420 Put the dll in the same folder as the exe.

Comment: I've Put all the dll files but the code is printing this message, and i'm not understanding what it needs plus i've checked the database and nothing is changed 

code ==>http://codepad.org/3313MBsX
msg ==> http://i.imgur.com/SOGBkuz.jpg